# google Appscript shows error even though i copy pasted the exact code from documentation

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm new here (in fact, i'm just starting to learn about coding myself) so I'm sorry if i asked stupid question.
I'm trying to learn to code using google Appscript by following tutorial but somehow everything produced an error. here's the code in code.gs:

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

both produced an error, the doGet produced
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='

while the include function produced
Exception: Bad value

i really don't know where i went wrong, i even copy pasted these from their documentation

edit: fixed the 1st error thanks to the answer, but the second error remains.
here's the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Icon -->
    <link href="https://cdn.lineicons.com/2.0/LineIcons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <?!=include("page-css"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Well, Hello There!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

(the 1st error was because i wrote

```
<?! = include("page-css"); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?!=include("page-css"); ?>
```

also, the page-css is still empty,

```
<style>

</style>
```

i wrap it in  because i can't make .css file in google appscript

#### Update:

i tried to run the function in the appscript (that play button) and it produce exception : bad value @ line 7 (the return HtmlService line). but when i tried to test deployment, it works the way i expected it to be.

Comment: I think that in your question, the HTML of `page` might have the issue. So, can you provide your current HTML of `page`?

Comment: You're right, i didn't know the error could come from the html. i wrote <?! = include instead of <?!=include, fixed that one, thanks. but the second error still remains.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your 2nd issue, I cannot understand it. I apologize for my poor English skill.  Can I ask you about the detail of your 2nd issue?

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to your issue. As far as I can tell, it has nothing to do with PHP or JS (I removed those tags for you)

Comment: apologize for the wrong tags. i just thought that the include functions was php and the gs as JS

Comment: I think  you should remove the semi colons out of  `<?!=include("page-css"); ?>`  you can write it like this: `<?!= include("page-css") ?>`  the include is just a function call.

Comment: [<?!= ... ?>](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets)

Comment: @Tanaike i tried to run the function in the appscript (that play button) and it produce exception : bad value @ line 7 (the return HtmlService line). but when i tried to test deployment, it works the way i expected it to be. I am tempted to just leave the error be.

Comment: @MetaMan Hi! thanks for replying. I've tried removing it, but it doesn't change anything. so i put it back to avoid confusion. is it considered best practice to not use it?

Comment: I never use it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that your issue has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [your comment to Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614020/google-appscript-shows-error-even-though-i-copy-pasted-the-exact-code-from-docum#comment119513540_67614020):

> i tried to run the function in the appscript (that play button) and it produce exception : bad value @ line 7 (the return HtmlService line). but when i tried to test deployment, it works the way i expected it to be. I am tempted to just leave the error be.

You are getting this error because, if you run the function `include` from the script editor, the parameter `filename` is not defined. Therefore, you are trying to create an HTML output based on an unexisting file, and consequently you get an error:

> **Throws**
>
> [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) — if the file wasn't found or the HTML in it is malformed

If you want to test the function on the script editor, you could set a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) that matches one of your HTML files:

```
function include(filename = "page-css") {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createhtmloutputfromfilefilename)

Comment: thank you!! you solve the second "error" problem then. it irks me that there's an error when it works just fine, gave me a sense of impending doom. with that being said, how do I mark my question as "solved"?